# X-axis labels bunched together in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I am using R to plot values, and am attempting to replace the x axis labels with my own as follows:

```
plot(date, value, xaxt="n", xlab="Year", ylab="value")
axis(1, at=seq(min(year), max(year), by=10))
```

where min(year) = 1969 and max(year) = 2016.

The plot itself looks fine, but the x axis tick labels are not:

[image: plot with incorrect x axis tick labels]

As you can see the x axis ticks are all bunched up together instead of being evenly spread across the x-axis and only showing one of the years.

What am I missing?

Thank you!!

My source data looks like this:

```
 site year       date  value
1  MLO 1969 1969-08-20 323.95
2  MLO 1969 1969-08-27 324.58
3  MLO 1969 1969-09-02 321.61
4  MLO 1969 1969-09-12 321.15
5  MLO 1969 1969-09-24 321.15
6  MLO 1969 1969-10-03 320.54
```

and the values are:

```
date <- data[["date"]]
value <- data[["value"]]
year <- data[["year"]]
```

Comment: What is ``min(date)`` and ``max(date)``?  What is their class?

Comment: > min(year)
[1] 1969
> max(year)
[1] 2016
> class(min(year))
[1] "integer"

Comment: Date: is a data frame of strings "1969-08-20" and so on, the class of date is "factor"

Comment: Basically I'm trying to get meaningful tick labels on the x axis; if I just leave it up to plot(), nothing good happens because they are strings, and there's too many of them. Another option might be to try to convert the "date" frame values into actual R dates and see if it does something smarter...

Comment: Can you add `head(data)`, so that we can see what your dataframe looks like.

Comment: Done @Rishi ! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you're treating `factor`s of dates as if they are numerically relevant. Internally, a `factor` is just an `integer`, which means the fact that they plot sequentially is convenient but does not reflect the effective separation between the actual `$date`s.

Instead, convert them into actual `Date` objects and use that. (Due to small data, I changed the data slightly)

```
dat <- read.table(text='site year       date  value
  MLO 1969 1965-08-20 323.95
  MLO 1969 1968-08-27 324.58
  MLO 1969 1970-09-02 321.61
  MLO 1969 1972-09-12 321.15
  MLO 1969 1979-09-24 321.15
  MLO 1969 1983-10-03 320.54', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

From here, (mostly) your plot.

```
plot(value ~ date, data=dat, type='b', xaxt="n", xlab="Year", ylab="value")
years <- as.Date(format(range(dat$date), "%Y-01-01"))
years <- seq(years[1], years[2], '5 years')
str(years)
#  Date[1:4], format: "1965-01-01" "1970-01-01" "1975-01-01" "1980-01-01"
axis(1, at=years, labels=format(years, '%Y'))
# or more directly (thanks @thelatemail)
axis.Date(1, years, format="%Y")
```

The reason I use both `at` and `labels` is so that we can get the value/location of a full `Date` object while preserving the printing-format of year-only.

[image: simple datewise plot]

Comment: You can also do `axis.Date(1, years, format="%Y")` to be able to use the `format=` option directly as well.

Comment: @r2evans Oh my gosh, thank you!!!! Yes, exactly what I needed, and am learning so much from your code example.